# How to convert JavaScript array of objects into an array?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert the array of objects into an array of a key present in the object. The desired output should be an [array of username].

```json
[  
   {  
      "UserID":"66e7ba60-9ad2-41a1-83f2-f8cf97afb97d",
      "UserName":"Karthik Kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikbuyer@365media.in",
      "UserType":"2"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"292716bd-5386-4371-8ef9-e8ebbebb432f",
      "UserName":"karthik kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikvendor@365media.in",
      "UserType":"3"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"d23eb3e0-1bcd-429f-9268-6cdd95772b08",
      "UserName":"karthikeyan rajendran",
      "UserEmail":"kartik1235@gmail.com",
      "UserType":"3"
   }
]
```

Comment: can you please share what output format exactly you want?

Comment: it's still not entirely clear what you want.

Comment: `array.map(v => v.UserName);`

Comment: i want the output to be  [karthik kumar, karthikeyan rajendran]

Comment: its not an array. its an object.

Comment: @karty—the code in the OP is an array literal with elements that are objects (it even says "*…convert the array of object*"). If that's not correct, fix the OP.

Comment: @karty did you try it yourself before posting it on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check this updated code where it converts usernames in to array values**

```js
var myarray = [  
   {  
      "UserID":"66e7ba60-9ad2-41a1-83f2-f8cf97afb97d",
      "UserName":"Karthik Kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikbuyer@365media.in",
      "UserType":"2"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"292716bd-5386-4371-8ef9-e8ebbebb432f",
      "UserName":"karthik kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikvendor@365media.in",
      "UserType":"3"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"d23eb3e0-1bcd-429f-9268-6cdd95772b08",
      "UserName":"karthikeyan rajendran",
      "UserEmail":"kartik1235@gmail.com",
      "UserType":"3"
   }
]

var value = myarray.map(x => x.UserName)

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function.

```
array.map(x => x.UserName)
```

Comment: its not an array. its an object.

Comment: No, it's an array of objects, and it is converted to an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use map function: [Map reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

In this case:

```
var arr = [  
   {  
      "UserID":"66e7ba60-9ad2-41a1-83f2-f8cf97afb97d",
      "UserName":"Karthik Kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikbuyer@365media.in",
      "UserType":"2"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"292716bd-5386-4371-8ef9-e8ebbebb432f",
      "UserName":"karthik kumar",
      "UserEmail":"karthikvendor@365media.in",
      "UserType":"3"
   },
   {  
      "UserID":"d23eb3e0-1bcd-429f-9268-6cdd95772b08",
      "UserName":"karthikeyan rajendran",
      "UserEmail":"kartik1235@gmail.com",
      "UserType":"3"
   }
]

var value = arr.map(function (element) {
    return element.UserName;
});
```

Comment: its not an array. its an object.

Comment: It's an array of objects. @karty.